# Encoding issue with ansi text received through bluetooth in Android

Tags: android, string, gps, bluetooth

I am trying to read data from a Bluetooth GPS device on Android. 
I have modified the BluetoothChat sample from the Android SDK to create RFComm socket using reflection.
Looks like the values i receive are not encoded correctly. I get some unprintable characters as a result.
But the GetBlue app from the Android market is able to correctly display the NMEA strings.
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

This got solved after specifying an appropriate UUID for connection.
Please see BlueGPS4Droid(http://sourceforge.net/p/bluegps4droid/home) for an example.